# Extract Seq using Kafka Streams

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to read a Kafka topic, do some processing based on that, and store the results in another topic.

My code looks like below:

```
builder
   .stream(settings.Streams.inputTopic)
   .mapValues[Seq[Product]]((e: EventRecord) ⇒ fx(e))
   // Something needs to be done here...
   .to(settings.Streams.outputTopic)
```

The `fx(e)` function does some processing and returns a `Seq[Product]`. I'd like to store all products as a separate entry in the topic. Problem is that the messages read from the topic contain multiple products, hence the return value for `fx(e)`.

Is it possible to embed this behaviour in the stream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`flatMapValues`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#flatMapValues(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper)) instead of `mapValues`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters.asJavaIterableConverter

builder
  .stream(settings.Streams.inputTopic)
  .flatMapValues(e => fx(e).toIterable.asJava)
  .to(settings.Streams.outputTopic)
```